# looking for tools / techniques to monitor memory usage in the browser

Tags: debugging, memory-management, browser

We are building an application that makes extensive use of css3 transformations. apparently, transform scale, rotate3d, and of course large images are all factors that cause a memory usage threshold to be reached once a critical number of  html elements are on the page.

The goals is to  maximize the number of elements that can be added, with minimal compromise in features of css3d transforms  or image size/ quality.

I am looking for tools / techniques to monitor the memory usage in the browser on as detailed a level as is technologically available.

Currently working with google chrome.

bonus: any tips for efficiently working with images / css3 transformations / animations?

Comment: currently learning the intricacies of chrome debugger and running test pages such as http://jsfiddle.net/khKqr/embedded/result/

Comment: chrome heap snapshot profiler shows 5.58mb memory usage. after I make a change that leads to what seems to be a memory-limit related problem (adding more large rotated images to the dom) the heap shapshot shows 5.69mb   working on inspecting the details of the heap shapshot to gain more information

Answer (score 0):

the best thing I found so far (in chome) is the *timeline* feature of the chrome web developer tools.

Its amazingly rigorous and detailed. you can profile down to a very low level including intricate details of paint events, css selectors, and of course javascript functions.